# Correct syntax for MySQL UPDATE ... JOIN ... CASE?

Tags: mysql, join, case

I am at loss to figure out how to do an UPDATE with CASE and JOIN. This example is from my Drupal database. `content_type` has `nid` as its primary key; `term_node`, on the other hand, can have multiple rows with the same `nid` matched to different `tid`s. MySQL will happily parse a query based on WHERE:

```
UPDATE `content_type`
LEFT JOIN `term_node` USING(nid)
 SET
  `field_m03` = 1
   WHERE tid = 696;
```

The above updates all rows in `content_type` which have an `nid` matched to `(tid = 696)` in `term_node`, as it should.
But when I try to string several conditions with CASE it won't work. No errors, but 0 rows affected:

```
UPDATE `content_type`
LEFT JOIN `term_node` USING(nid)
 SET
  `field_m03` = (CASE
   WHEN (tid = '696') THEN '1'
   WHEN (tid = '697') THEN '2'
   WHEN (tid = '698') THEN '3'
   WHEN (tid = '699') THEN '4'
   WHEN (tid = '700') THEN '5'
   ELSE `field_m03`
   END);
```

Also tried without the parentheses and single quotes, no change.

Comment: `field_m03` is from table `content_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems correct.

If your MySQL server has safe updates ([SQL_SAFE_UPDATES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates)) turned on, then your server will abort any updates that don't have a `WHERE` or `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an answer why it doesn't work, but I would like to suggest you to think over it again.

Your `UPDATE` would require a full table scan. Single updates could use indexes, provided that the given `tid`s are only a small set of the `tid`s actually present.

So it might be easier and cheaper to issue single `UPDATE`s, or at least restrict the range of the `UPDATE` with

```
... WHERE tid BETWEEN 696 AND 700
```

.

Comment: @Pedro, definitely check out my answer and the SQL_SAFE_UPDATES setting then.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `ALIAS` in your tables?

```
UPDATE `content_type` a
LEFT JOIN `term_node` b USING(nid)
 SET
  a.`field_m03` = (CASE
   WHEN (b.tid = '696') THEN '1'
   WHEN (b.tid = '697') THEN '2'
   WHEN (b.tid = '698') THEN '3'
   WHEN (b.tid = '699') THEN '4'
   WHEN (b.tid = '700') THEN '5'
   ELSE a.`field_m03`
   END);
```

Comment: Definitely more readable with aliases, but this isn't likely the solution. MySQL would complain if the field names were ambiguous.